# getgroups() on macOS is not returning all the supplementary groups, but instead just the primary group

Tags: c, macos, darwin, usergroups

'id' command does give me all the supplementary groups, but the following code is just returning the primary groups for which the use belongs:

```
gid_size = getgroups(0, NULL); //1 is getting returned here
grouplist = malloc(gid_size * sizeof(gid_t));
getgroups(gid_size, grouplist); //Even with gid_size>1, only primary groups is returned.
```

My question is, whether there's any other alternative way to get all the supplementary groups on macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get up to 16 more groups by invoking `initgroups()` first, but even this is not ideal.

From the [`initgroups(3)` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/initgroups.3.html):

> Processes should not use the group ID numbers from `getgroups(2)` to determine a user's group membership.  The list obtained from `getgroups()` may only be a partial list of a user's group membership.  Membership checks should use the `mbr_gid_to_uuid(3)`, `mbr_uid_to_uuid(3)`, and `mbr_check_membership(3)` functions.

So if you're trying to check if the user is a member of a specific group, the `mbr_*()` functions are the way to go.

Note that the [source code of the `id` command is available](https://opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-203/id/) and based on a very quick inspection it looks like it uses the undocumented `getgrouplist_2()`.

It [looks like](https://gist.github.com/erikng/2c0cc3065be5d29209c63fcc588c4765) this is a variant of the [`getgrouplist()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/getgrouplist.3.html) function, but without the 16-group limitation.

I don't think this function is declared in any public headers, `id.c` uses the prototype

```
int32_t getgrouplist_2(const char *, gid_t, gid_t **);
```